# Twilio auto response SMS to be sent when the landline number is called

Tags: twilio

We have merchants onboarded on our platform and want to provide an auto-response SMS feature to our merchants.

Merchants already have their landline number. The mechanism needed is to send an auto-response SMS to any customer calling the landline number to receive an SMS with some specific instructions.

Is it possible? I see that it is possible when I use a Twilio number but need this supported for an existing landline number

Answer (score 1):

Take a Look at Hosted Numbers, which allows landline numbers to support SMS.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/hosted-numbers